# How do I find the Kernel and Range of composition linear transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Let $G(x,y,z)=(0,x+y+z)$ and $H(x,y)=(x−y,0,x)$.
>
> Find the kernel and range of $G\circ H : \Re^2 → \Re^2$

**My Approach**

Finding $G\circ H$:

$$G\circ H= G(H(x,y))$$

$$=G(x-y,0,x)$$

$$=(0,x-y+x)=(0,2x-y)$$

How does one find the Kernel and Range of this? I can't find it in my book.

Comment: It should be $(0,2x-y)$. The kernel is just $\langle (1,2) \rangle$ and the range is just $\langle (0, 1) \rangle$.

Comment: @S.W.Cheung Thank you for spotting the typo :)

Comment: @S.W.Cheung How is the kernel and range that? :) I dont understand....how did you get that values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the kernel, you're looking for $(x,y)$ such that $(0,2x-y) = (0,0)$. So $(x,y)$ will be in the kernel if and only if $y=2x$. So the elements of the kernel are the elements of the form $(x,2x) = x(1,2)$. In other words, this is the span of the vector $(1,2)$ Or the line y=2x, if you like.

To find the range, you need to determine for what vectors $(a,b)$ is there a vector $(x,y)$ with $(0,2x-y) = (a,b).$ Clearly we must have $a=0$. Now if $b$ is any real number, then $G(H(0,-b)) = (0,b)$. The vectors of the form $(0,b)$ are just the vectors in the span of $(0,1)$. So the range is just the $y$-axis.

Comment: +1 Just to make it clearer to me, shouldn't it be "The vectors of the form (0,-b)" ?

Comment: The statement $G(H(0,-b)) = (0,b)$ shows $(0,b)$ is in the range for any real number $b$, not $(0,-b)$. Although it is still true that $(0,-b)$ is in the range as well.

Comment: I see. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Since $G \circ H(x,y) = (0,2x-y)$, the kernel of $G \circ H$ is given by
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{ker}(G \circ H) & = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: (0,2x-y) = (0,0)\}\\
& = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: y = 2x\}\\
& = \{t(2,1) \in \mathbb{R}^2: t \in \mathbb{R}\}\\
& = \langle (2,1) \rangle.
\end{split}
\end{equation}
For $t \in \mathbb{R}$, we have
$$(G \circ H)(0,-t) = (0,t).$$
Hence the range of $G \circ H$ is given by
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{Im}(G \circ H) & = \{(0,2x-y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}\\
& = \{(0,t)\in \mathbb{R}^2: t \in \mathbb{R}\}\\
& = \langle (0,1) \rangle.
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: +1 What does Im stand for? Just out of curiosity

Comment: The image set, which is just the range. There are different notations but the book I used for teaching in the last semester use this notation.

Comment: Oh okay :) Thank you alot